# contact form in email not returning values

Tags: php, forms, mailer

I'm using `CKEditor` to create a `html mailer` in which a contact form is being sent to email.
The problem is, there is no value being received on submission of that form in email.

**Contact Form in E-Mail (code)**

```
<form action="http://techindiainfotech.com/mail.php" method="post" name="test">
    <p>Your Name: <input maxlength="75" name="name" size="75" type="text" /></p>

    <p>Mobile Number: <input maxlength="10" name="mobile" size="10" type="text" /></p>

    <p>Business Name: <input maxlength="100" name="business" size="100" type="text" /></p>

    <p><input name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**Handler - mail.php**

```
if ($_POST['sub'] != '') {
    unset($_POST['sub']);
    echo "Details received:<br>";
    foreach ($_POST as $val) {
        echo "$val<br>";
    }
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.techindiainfotech.com/files/contact_us.php");
    exit();
}
```

**Screenshot from gmail's Message Text Garbled**

[image: Message Text Garbled]

Comment: You need to post your handler also. That's where the actual problem is. Chances are, your variables may not be properly assigned, or other variables not properly concatenated, could be 100 different things.

Comment: why do you post via http, mail.php is not in the same server?

Comment: what is your PHP code? try to run php cody phpinfo() to see all submitted valuse.

Comment: @meda That doesn't make a difference, just as long as the OP has control over the domain/file to action.

Comment: @meda: then what should I use?

Comment: please check edit for `php` code

Comment: @MohammadFaisal That's your entire code? I see no `mail()` here, plus why are you `unset`ting your POST value?

Comment: I'm `unset`ting the value because for now, I don't wanna show value of submit button. what is the need for `mail()` here? That's the handler code, when form submitted

Comment: @MohammadFaisal What is the need for `mail()` you ask? Your subject reads as ***"contact form in mail not returning values"*** How do you expect to send anything? Is there a *magic* feature I'm not aware of? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: since you are unsetting the $_POST['sub'] values before displaying them, the foreach loop will not display anything. You might want to do var_dump($_POST) at different points in your code to see what is the value for the $_POST variables.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: the word `mail` here doesn't belong to `mail()`. I've sent a mail to user which contains a `contact form` and that values I need on my server back

Comment: @MohammadFaisal You should have worded your question in different fashion then, I seem to have misinterpreted it then.

Comment: @Maximus2012: He's just unsetting the submit button, not the entire array. So, it should work. See http://3v4l.org/soL8h

Comment: @AmalMurali that is correct.

Comment: I've used `print_r($_POST)` to check what values do `$_POST` holds but it results in empty array `Array()`. If you guys can provide me your emails then I can send you that form and on submit you can check that too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything was fine except for the one, the form `action` attribute.
I'm submitting the form to `http://techindiainfotech.com/mail.php` but due to `.htaccess` it is being redirected to `http://www.techindiainfotech.com/mail.php` and that's why the *request has been lost* (I'm not getting the appropriate word here).

So, I just need to change in my `action` attribute which is, submit my form to `http://www.techindiainfotech.com/mail.php` not to `http://techindiainfotech.com/mail.php`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_POST['sub'] != '') {
    unset($_POST['sub']);
```

The above code means: if `$_POST['sub']` is not an empty string, evaluate the statements below.

If your form wasn't submitted, `$_POST['sub'];` will be undefined and PHP will throw an error saying `Undefined index`.

I'd use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) instead to properly check if the form was submitted or not.

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    # code ...
}
```

The following should work:

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) 
{
    unset($_POST['sub']);
    echo "Details received:<br>";
    foreach ($_POST as $val) 
    {
        echo "$val<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used that syntax many times and there's no problem. I'm just unsetting the `sub` not all values. And as `$_POST['sub']!=''` evaluated to true at first why do i need to recheck for `$_POST['sub']!=''`?

Comment: I need to display only the remaining values in `$_POST`

Comment: `if ($_POST['sub'] != '') {` means, if it is not an empty string. It doesn't mean it's not set. See: `var_dump((bool)('' === null))` returning false

Comment: @DanFromGermany: that's what I meant. Sorry about the incorrect wording. I've updated the answer :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Better, but it still won't solve the OPs issue ;/

Answer (score 1):

Your form is so simple and the `$_POST` loop, that it narrows down the error sources:

- file base: scripts are not in the folder you expect
- CKEditor throws out HTML, either you strip it or,... have a look into the HTML sourcecode.
- Use `print_r($_POST);` at the beginning of mail.php
- enable PHP debugging / error reporting: http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/
- if you have javascript we  cannot see in your sample code, remove it for further testing

**Update:**

- the CKEditor changes your inputs in a way that they are not anymore labeled by `name` attributes or renders the form in any other invalid form (don't think that's the problem)

I copied your sample code onto my webserver and it's working. You might have something in your real code that doesn't appear in the code above.

Comment: 3rd point is good, but I'd tried that too and found the output as `Array()`

Comment: I'd added a screenshot from `gmail`'s `Message Text garbled`. I've not found any evidence for your statement "`the CKEditor changes your inputs in a way that they are not anymore labeled by name attributes or renders the form in any other invalid form`"

Comment: Are you having a FORM inside an eMail ? eMail clients do evaluate HTML VERY strict. I'm not sure if this is even supposed to work - if you use the form from your website it does actually work. You could try to include full HTML structure (`<html><head>...`) into the email but I dont think it will work in any way.

Comment: I've seen many times a mail with query form and the values got submitted to their server